# woocommerce php snippets for proceeded to checkout to know user is login or not

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce theme shopkeeper and i have problem with proceed to checkout functionality 
i need a php snippet code for checking  the user is login or not when he click a button of proceed to checkout on cart page

Answer (score 0):

You have to use simple wordpress function to check is a user logged in or not.
 **[is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)**

Checks if the current visitor is a logged in user.
it returns (bool) True if user is logged in, false if not logged in.

```
  <?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
    } else {
        echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check user in on checkout page or not, if so then do the checking; or if you have your own function then you can simply wordpress `is_user_logged_in()` function.

```
add_action('wp', 'xyz_checkLoggedIn');

function xyz_checkLoggedIn() {
    if (is_checkout()) {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            //user is logged in
        } else {
            //user is not logged in
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**The code is tested and fully functional.**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'check_if_user_loggedin');
function check_if_user_loggedin() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Logged user';
} else {
    echo 'Guest user!';
}
}
```